# What is the purpose of interpolationId in angular $translate

Tags: angularjs, string-interpolation, angular-translate

From Angular translate documentation:

`$translate(translationId[, interpolateParams], interpolationId);`

What is the purpose of `interpolationId` parameter, can you also give an example?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the purpose of interpolationId parameter...

The purpose of `interpolationId` is to reference the identifier returned by `getInterpolationIdentifier` of a custom interpolation that has been added.  You can add a custom interpolation using [`$translateProvider.addInterpolation`](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateProvider).

This is documented better in angular-translate's [Pluralization documentation](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/14_pluralization).

> ...can you also give an example?

Here's an example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/cDpNzZ6T6TSc13Qmji77

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  $translate('greeting', {}, 'custom'): {{ customGreeting }}
  <br> $translate('greeting', {}): {{ regularGreeting }}
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'pascalprecht.translate'
]);

app.config(["$translateProvider",
  function($translateProvider){
    $translateProvider.translations('en',{
      "greeting" : "Welcome Dinesh" 
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

    $translateProvider.addInterpolation('customInterpolator');
  }
]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$translate',
  function ($scope, $translate) {
    $translate('greeting', {}, 'custom').then(function (result) {
      $scope.customGreeting = result;
    });
    $translate('greeting', {}).then(function (result) {
      $scope.regularGreeting = result;
    });
  }
]);

app.factory('customInterpolator', [
  function () {
    var customInterpolator = {};

    customInterpolator.$get = function () {
    };

    customInterpolator.setLocale = function (locale) {
    };

    customInterpolator.getInterpolationIdentifier = function () {
        return 'custom';
    };

    customInterpolator.interpolate = function (string, interpolateParams) {
        return 'My custom interpolation message';
    };

    return customInterpolator;
  }
]);
```